# How to check what node authoring a block with Aura in the Polkadot.js App?

Tags: polkadot-js, aura, ui

There is a way to see what node authoring a specific block in the Polkadot app?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is impossible.

Some nodes even run in a private network address.

How did you identify that?

Comment: So we don't have information about the author of the block in the header?

Comment: You can have the validator's information. But you can not access the validator's node.

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/explorer/query/0x1e9082ad8ecb5b6210efcbf3515f021c4216857da35149ea82c11d117ad0c00f

You can easily find the author of this block, `13NFKRvvSoKCAg3Q8HjigdBNvg5ypC8Rh6aziQjfUF2YspLV`.

Comment: But why I can't see it when I run a local blockchain? https://imgur.com/a/cDQwBcI I'm running 4 authority nodes with Aura/Grandpa

Comment: Maybe you need to add the pallet-authorship to your chain.

Comment: You missed this https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/0e50e33b9622d1b8bf684340fb17eb59e4a4f987/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L1423.

Comment: Yes sorry, I had already fix that like this: https://github.com/Datagen-Project/Datagen-Substrate-Grant/blob/744d01400825f7b4ebd8a1ab621739a13e19a09a/fast_blockchain/runtime/src/lib.rs#L346

Comment: Make a new question for this specific problem https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5038/pallet-authorship-implementation-doesnt-work-with-aura-consensus