# pallet_authorship implementation doesn't work with Aura consensus

Tags: aura, authorship

I'm trying to get the authors of the blocks using the `pallet_authorship` but when I inspect the authorship on the polkadot.js app I get `none` as result.

[image]

This is my implementation of the `pallet_authorship` for the runtime: https://github.com/Datagen-Project/Datagen-Substrate-Grant/blob/744d01400825f7b4ebd8a1ab621739a13e19a09a/fast_blockchain/runtime/src/lib.rs#L302